# Adding a class onto a div on <th> click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have a table header with 10 columns. Inside each one of these columns is some text and one div. The purpose of the div, is to have an image of an arrow that indicates if the table is being sorted ascending or descending.

Now, when the user clicks on the th, I want jQuery to add a class of .headerSortUp to the div inside THAT th.. Here's what I got so far:

HTML: (for the header column)

```
<table cellspacing="0" id="open-orders" class="enhanced tablesorter">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="persist essential"><a href="#" rel="Symbol"></a>Company 
        <div class="sorter"></div></th>
        <th class="hidden"><a href="#" rel="grade"></a>Stock<br class="rwd"/>Grade
        <div class="sorter"></div></th>
        <th class="essential"><a href="#" rel="price"></a>GTC<br class="rwd" />
          Price 
        <div class="sorter"></div></th>
        <th class="optional"><a href="#" rel="buy-date"></a>Buy<br class="rwd" />
          Date 
        <div class="sorter"></div></th>
        <th class="optional"><a href="#" rel="allocation"></a>Allocation
        <div class="sorter"></div></th>
        <th class="optional"><a href="#" rel="quantity"></a>Share<br class="rwd" />
          Quantity 
        <div class="sorter"></div></th>
        <th class="optional"><a href="#" rel="yield"></a>Yield 
        <div class="sorter"></div></th>
        <th class="optional"><a href="#" rel="ex-dividend"></a>Ex-<br class="rwd" />
          Dividend 
        <div class="sorter"></div></th>
        <th><a href="#" rel="cprice"></a>Current<br class="rwd" />
          Price 
        <div class="sorter"></div></th>
        <th><a href="#" rel="return"></a>Current<br class="rwd" />
          Return 
        <div class="sorter"></div></th>
        <th class="leftnote">Notes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#open-orders tr th").click(function(){
        $("#open-orders tr th").removeClass("headerSortUp");
        $(this).addClass("headerSortUp");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
table.tablesorter thead tr th .sorter .headerSortUp {
    background-image: url("/wcmedia/asc1.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr th .sorter .headerSortDown {
    background-image: url("/wcmedia/desc1.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
}
```

I do not understand why my jQuery isn't adding the class to the div.. Could anyone point out why my jQuery isn't working? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `this` in `$(this).addClass("headerSortUp");` refers to the items that was clicked. In this case, that's `$("#open-orders tr th")`, not the `div`.

```
$("#open-orders tr th").click(function(){
    $("#open-orders").find(".headerSortUp").removeClass("headerSortUp");
    $(this).find('div').addClass("headerSortUp");
});
```

Also, your CSS is wrong for this scenario. You don't want the space after `.sorter`:

```
table.tablesorter thead tr th .sorter.headerSortUp {
    background-image: url("/wcmedia/asc1.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr th .sorter.headerSortDown {
    background-image: url("/wcmedia/desc1.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
```

Actually, I doubt there's a need to be that specific. That's a *really* slow selector. `.headerSortUp {}` is probably enough. Add a single element to the left if you need it.

**OPTION 2**
You could also leave your JS alone and change your CSS:

```
.headerSortUp .sorter{
    background-image: url("/wcmedia/asc1.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
}
.headerSortDown  .sorter {
    background-image: url("/wcmedia/desc1.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
}
```

This is saying apply these styles to any `.sorter` element within `.headerSortUp` and `.headerSortDown`

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you for the explanation as well.. You're the man! I'll except the answer in 7 minutes (I have to wait that long before I can accept it.)

Comment: Glad it helped. NB @Danko's comment "Remember to make the bg image visible you need dimensions on the element"

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your CSS selector; with this:

> $("#open-orders tr th")

You are adding the class name to the `th` element and with your CSS selector:

> table.tablesorter thead tr th .sorter .headerSortDown

You target an element with class `headerSortDown` inisde `.sorter` what you need is change the CSS selectors to this:

```
table.tablesorter thead tr th.headerSortUp .sorter  {
  background-image: url("/wcmedia/asc1.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr th.headerSortDown  .sorter {
  background-image: url("/wcmedia/desc1.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
}
```

Matching  `th` elements with that classname.

**Remember to make the bg image visible you need dimensions on the element**